# How do I extract the prefix of a string till the last instance of a specific character?

Tags: kusto-explorer

for eampaple, the specific character is "_":

let str = "a_b_c_d_1";

how can I extract "a_b_c_d" ?

Answer (score 0):

Found a way to do so, I believe there are more elegant ones.

```
let str = "a_b_c_d_1";
print(strcat_array(array_shift_right(split(str, "_"), 1),""))
```